# How to improve the time performance of a C++ pthread code that uses Barriers

Tags: c++, pthreads

I wrote a code for the simulation of a communication system. Within this communication system, there is a part that I am running in parallel using pthreads.  It basically corrects errors that are caused by the channel.

When I receive a frame of bits, 3 components of the algorithm run over the bits. Usually, they are run one after the other, which results in optimal performance, but a huge delay.

The idea is to make them run in parallel. But to get optimal performance, the 3 components much process each bit at the same time.

If I just run them in parallel I obtain bad results, but quite a fast performance. So I used barriers to synchronize the process, where each bit is processed by the three components before allowing them to jump to the following bit.

The performance of this method is optimal. But the code is running really slow, I am taking even slower than the serial implementation.

The code runs on Ubuntu with GCC compiler.

EDIT: One more question, do threads go to sleep while they are waiting for the barrier to open? and if so, how do I prevent them from doing so?

Comment: the input buffer should be read only for all the threads, and each thread should have output buffer for its own. this way you won't need any locks, and can process in parallel.

Comment: That is a great solution, however, the components are dependent on each other, they are recursive in nature.

Comment: How you spawn the threads? are you using some kind of thread pool?

Comment: I put pthread_create in a loop that calls the threads function 3 times which in turn calls the corresponding component.

Comment: Put your processing in an FPGA.

Answer (score 2):

If you literally have to synchronise after every *bit*, then quite simply threading is not going to be an appropriate approach.  The synchronisation overhead is going to far exceed the cost of computation, so you will be better off doing it in a single thread.

Can you split the work up at a higher level? For example, have an entire frame processed by a single thread, but have multiple frames processed in parallel?

Comment: it doesn't have to be a bit by bit synchronization. Which gives me the idea to only put barriers at 25%, 50% and 75% of the block length.  

Thanks for your answer. I would like to note that I already process blocks in parallel, in actual simulation, but I turn it off when I analyze my results.

Comment: Ahh, so the point is just to not allow one thread to get too far in front of the others (or one to fall too far behind).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution, USING NO MUTEX.

Lets say you have 4 threads: main thread reading some input, the other 3 threads processing its chunk by chunk. a thread can process a chunk just after the previous one done processing it.

so you have a data type for a chunk:

```
class chunk{
 byte buffer[CHUNK_SIZE];
 char status; // use char for atomic input, c++11 can use std::atomic_int.
public: 
 chunk():status(0); 
};
```

and you have a list of chunks:

```
std::list<chunk> chunks;
```

all threads running on chunks, till they reach end of list, but wait till status reach a condition, main thread set status to 1 when input chunk is done. 1st thread wait till status is 1, means input was done and set status to 2 when done, thread 2 wait till status is 2 means thread 1 was done, and when done processing this chunk, set status to 3, and so on. finally, main thread wait till status is 4 to get results

Important when setting the status, to use a `=` not `++` to make it as atomic as possible.